# Swapping nodes in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, swap

I have a linked list with this values as examples: 4 5 3 2 7, now I want to swap each node with previous one, like this:

```
4 5 3 2 7 // this beginning of list
5 4 3 2 7
5 3 4 2 7
5 3 2 4 7
5 3 2 7 4 // the list should now become like this
```

But unfortunately when I parse for the output I stuck in infinite loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int p;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, n;
    node *nod = NULL;
    node *nod_tmp = NULL;
    node *nod2 = NULL;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        nod_tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d", &nod_tmp->p);
        nod_tmp->next = nod;
        nod = nod_tmp;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < n)
    {   
        nod_tmp = nod;
        nod = nod->next;
        nod->next = nod_tmp;
        ++i;
    }

    while(nod != NULL)
    {   

        printf("%d\n", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the infinite loop occurring?

Comment: @Nashibukasan When I traverse the list to print values. `. while(nod != NULL)
    {   

        printf("%d\n", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
    }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swapping nodes in a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970542/swapping-nodes-in-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swap code is wrong.  Should be something like this:

```
i = 1;
nod2 = nod;
while(i < n)
{   
    nod_tmp = nod2->next;
    nod2->next = nod_tmp->next;
    nod_tmp->next = nod2;
    ++i;
}
```

Or, since swapping every pair basically pushes the first element to the end you can do this:

```
nod_tmp = nod;
while (nod_tmp->next != NULL)
{
    nod_tmp = nod_tmp->next;
}
// nod_tmp now points to the last element
nod_tmp->next = nod;          // loop from the last element back to the first
nod = nod->next;              // move the list pointer to the second element
nod_tmp->next->next = NULL;   // break the loop at the new last element
```

Also, you may want to look at your input code.  As written it will build the list with the values in reverse order as entered, because it's always adding the next value to the head of the list.

**Update**

To avoid potential seg_faults the first loop above can be rewritten without the counter like this:

```
nod2 = nod;
nod_tmp = nod2->next;
while(nod_tmp != NULL)
{   
    nod2->next = nod_tmp->next;
    nod_tmp->next = nod2;
    nod_tmp = nod2->next;
}
```

**Update 2**

Here's full code that does what you want.  Rather than swap each pair of nodes it just pushes the first node to the end of the list.  I've also fixed the input loop so the list gets built in the correct order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int p;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, n;
    node *nod = NULL;
    node *nod_tmp = NULL;
    node *nod2 = NULL;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        nod_tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        scanf("%d", &nod_tmp->p);
        if (i == 0)
        {
            nod = nod2 = nod_tmp;
        }
        nod2->next = nod_tmp;
        nod2 = nod_tmp;
    }

    nod_tmp = nod;
    while (nod_tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        nod_tmp = nod_tmp->next;
    }
    // nod_tmp now points to the last element
    nod_tmp->next = nod;          // loop from the last element back to the first
    nod = nod->next;              // move the list pointer to the second element
    nod_tmp->next->next = NULL;   // break the loop at the new last element

    while(nod != NULL)
    {   

        printf("%d\n", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: on what line do you get the fault?

Comment: If you're using the first block of code in my answer then note the `n=1` at the beginning.  You only want to swap `n-1` times, so you you need to start counting from 1, not 0.

Comment: `nod2->next = nod_tmp->next`

Comment: Also, see updated answer for safer code that terminates at the end of the list, rather than relying on a counter to be correct.

Comment: It prints only the first element, basically I want to swap each node with previous one, please see the example I putted in my question.

Comment: You're right.  The swap code isn't updating the `nod` pointer to point to the new head of the list.  See the second update to my answer for working, tested code.

Answer (score 2):

This looks really strange:

```
while(i < n)
{   
    nod_tmp = nod;
    nod = nod->next;
    nod->next = nod_tmp;
    ++i;
}
```

Basically, you are looping 2 items assigning them to each other. You need to review this one.

**EDIT**

OK wrote it for you, seems to be working. (I do this by actual swapping list elements by pairs).

```
/// reading and stuff...

node *prev = NULL, *start = nod->next;
for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
{
    // look at this part, it makes everything obvious
    node *a = nod, *b = nod->next, *c = nod->next->next;

    b->next = a;
    a->next = c;

    nod = a; // changing the current node to next

    if(i == 0)
            {
        start = prev = b; // saving an actual start
            }
    else
    {
        prev->next = b;
        prev = prev->next;
    }

    // printing state to be sure
    for(node *tmp_start = start; tmp_start != NULL; tmp_start = tmp_start->next)
        printf("%d ", tmp_start->p);
    printf("\n");
}

printf("Final answer:\n");
while(start != NULL)
{   
    printf("%d ", start->p);
    start = start->next;
}
```

You need to input your data in reverse order (or change the reading function a little bit)

Example of using:

```
Enter n: 5 7 2 3 5 4
5 4 3 2 7
5 3 4 2 7
5 3 2 4 7
5 3 2 7 4
Final answer:
5 3 2 7 4
```

Comment: I stuck there, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: You list is, basically, read from the end to start, not as 5 lines you wrote. Just carefully watch this place and you'll see what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow this loop:

```
while(i < n)
{   
    nod_tmp = nod;         // 1
    nod = nod->next;       // 2
    nod->next = nod_tmp;   // 3
    ++i;
}
```

1. `nod_tmp` and `nod` now point to the same node.
2. `nod` is now pointing to `nod->next` (so `nod == nod_temp->next`)
3. `nod->next` is now pointing at `not_temp` which is the old address of `nod`.

Now that `nod->next` is pointing at the old address of `nod` (which `nod_temp` is also pointing to) you have a linked list whose tail points to its head.

This while loop might work better for you:

```
nod2 = nod;
nod_tmp = nod->next;
while(nod_tmp != NULL)
{   
    nod2->next = nod_tmp->next;
    nod_tmp->next = nod2;
    nod_tmp = nod2->next;
}
```

Comment: Ah, Fixed it but others have more complete answers than I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    i = 0;
    while(i < n)
    {
        printf("%d\n", nod->p);
        nod = nod->next;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: when you do nod->next = nod_tmp it loads entire nod_tmp into nod_next, not only a value, so your nod keeps getting bigger and bigger, should you do it with 2 nodes? it is a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear nod->next of the last entry in the list after you have finished swapping and before you print the results.

Answer (score 0):

c++11 way ..

Compile with: g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra mylist.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <class List>
void print(const List& list) {
    for (auto i : list)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <class List>
void swap(List& list) {
    auto i(list.begin());
    auto next(i);
    auto end(list.end());
    while (++next != end) {
        auto tmp = *i;
        *i++ = *next;
        *i = tmp;
        print(list);
    }
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::list<int> list {4, 5, 3, 2, 7};
    print(list);
    swap(list);
}
```

Comment: I have old compiler that doesn't support C++11, I need it in C language.

Comment: ah sorry, it's these darned stackoverflow tags; when I search for c++ it turns the '+'s into ' 's and gives me all the C stuff - I was actually wondering why the code looked all C like :) - I hope it helps evangelize a C user or two though still ;)